# Howto disable screensaver when vlc is running, under kde?

Tags: kde, vlc, screensaver

When `vlc` is running, the screen goes blank every 10 minutes. This requires to move the mouse or hit keyboard periodically when watching a movie.

This happens even after disabling the screensaver, in vlc:

- VLC → Tools → Preferences
- Show settings 'all' → Video → Disable Screensaver

Comment: not reproducible, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440550/3285

Comment: Not reproducible in your case... Please note that this was a self answered question, to help people facing the same problem.

Comment: see my update in my answer for proof.

Comment: "Proof" was not needed, but the supplement of information makes your answer useful.

Comment: I observe this bug with VLC 3.0.5-1-0-g653c0c1ca8 and xdg-screensaver 1.1.3+ on Fedora 29, KDE 5 (kded5 5.53.0, plasmashell 5.14.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the X screensaver is still enabled, as shown by typing `xset q` on the command line:

```
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  600
```

The solution has been given in [this thread](http://opensuse.14.x6.nabble.com/Disabling-display-power-management-td3039820.html).
Just issue `xset s noblank -dpms` on the command line.

But it is more convenient to create a `~/bin/disable_xsc.sh` file containing

```
#! /bin/bash

# disable the X screensaver
# The kde screensaver should still work, though
# http://opensuse.14.x6.nabble.com/Disabling-display-power-management-td3039820.html

xset s noblank -dpms

exit 0
```

**Make sure that this script is executable**

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/disable_xsc.sh
```

otherwise you would get a blinking "kwrite" in the taskbar, kde hanging, the taskbar responding very slowly, firefox would hang on startup, ...
if you forgot to chmod, just kill the offending kwrite process, and issue the chmod command.

Finally, going to the kde

configure desktop -> system administration -> startup and shutdown -> Autostart

Add script
in the "shell script path", type `~/bin/disable_xsc.sh`, leave the "Create symlink" checked. 
This script will be run on startup.

Note that the kde screensaver will still work correctly, when vlc is not running. Its configuration can be found in

configure desktop -> Hardware -> Display and monitor -> screen locker

Comment: Upgrading `xdg-screensaver`, as suggested in Evan's answer, is probably a better solution now.

Comment: For some reason, Evan's suggestion does not work on my system.

Answer (score 5):

The option to disable the screen saver, should work. At least now it sends the input to X11. So that will work. I have verified that it works for me despite having `xset q` report with VLC 2 and 3.

```
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
```

**History and Background:** Internally, [VLC uses `xdg-screensaver` to inhibit the screensaver](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/694399e23000232708b2d514a6a265cfc023ddde/modules/misc/inhibit/xdg.c#L62). There were a series of patches since this request that both addressed [DPMS](https://github.com/mtorromeo/xdg-utils/commit/b969809d9e33d049e9488dae065ee0cbddbc9404#diff-183b94329fb38f914a726696b8b2145b) and [KDE](https://github.com/mtorromeo/xdg-utils/commit/066b46418f454c0b7e1b5e1478f5f94d91276c14#diff-183b94329fb38f914a726696b8b2145b) (cinnamon). If this problem persists, consider upgrading your [`xdg-screensaver`](https://github.com/mtorromeo/xdg-utils/blob/master/scripts/xdg-screensaver.in) script (it's just a bash script).

For me, vlc is calling `xdg-screensaver reset` which calls [`xscreensaver-command`-deactivate which is documented as](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man3.html)

> This tells `xscreensaver` to pretend that there has just been user activity. This means that if the screensaver is active (the screen is blanked), then this command will cause the screen to un-blank as if there had been keyboard or mouse activity. If the screen is locked, then the password dialog will pop up first, as usual. **If the screen is not blanked, then this simulated user activity will re-start the countdown (so, issuing the `-deactivate` command periodically is one way to prevent the screen from blanking.)**

Comment: Nice to know it has been solved upstream, in a cleaner way.

Comment: @ederag yes. I can't confirm it's been solved but it seems highly likely, I can only say it no longer is reproducible under VLC 2, or VLC 3. However, check out the `xdg-screensaver` script above and try spamming `xdg-screensaver reset` and see if you can get your screen saver to go off. (no VLC needed, since any bug here involves `xdg-screensaver` and not vlc)

Comment: cloned the repo, `./configure`, `make`, `./scripts/xdg-screensaver reset`, the screensaver still activates. But openSUSE 42.2 is old now;your solution might help others.

Comment: @ederag did you `make install` or is vlc using the system's xdg-screensaver? Vlc will find the xdg-screensaver by using the environmental $PATH.

Comment: no vlc, since you wrote "no VLC needed, since any bug here involves xdg-screensaver and not vlc". But maybe vlc is periodically calling `xdg-screensaver reset` ? Shouldn't it call `xdg-screensaver suspend WindowID` ?

Comment: It's calling [`xdg-screensver reset`](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/694399e23000232708b2d514a6a265cfc023ddde/modules/misc/inhibit/xdg.c#L58) -- I linked to the code in the answer. If it is "calling" the xdg-screensaver in your system path, because you didn't `make install` xdg-screensaver then you'll still have the issue.

Comment: No, `reset` does not prevent the screensaver from activating. It just brings the desktop back from blank screen, *if* there is no **lock**. vlc should use `xdg-screensaver suspend WindowID` instead; that would really prevent the screen saver from activating. But I have no time for this now.

Comment: I'm not a VLC dev, feel free to file a bug report. I'm just saying that VLC periodically runs `reset` and that resets the activation-timer. I'm not sure why they're not calling suspend, except if they're afraid that VLC crashing before it can reissue xdg-screensaver activate

Comment: OK, then your solution can not work when the screensaver locks. Thanks for the discussion though (+1).

Comment: @ederag the screensaver can not lock when the timer is constantly reset.

Comment: As I said, the timer is *not* reset.

Comment: @ederag I don't have enough time to read to you everything, because you've made a habbit out of being wrong, but xdg-screensaver reset calls `xcreensaver -deactivate` which is documented as **This tells xscreensaver to pretend that there has just been user activity. [...]  then this simulated user activity will re-start the countdown (so, issuing the -deactivate command periodically is one way to prevent the screen from blanking.)**

Comment: It is generally better to avoid offensive comments like "you've made a habbit out of being wrong", with which I strongly disagree of course ;-). My previous comment was based on this test: `for i in {1..10}; do sleep 40 && ./scripts/xdg-screensaver reset; done`, which did not prevent blanking. I'm not saying you are wrong, just that here it does not work.

Comment: There is a **good** chance then that you have a found a valid bug against the most recent version of `xdg-screensaver` (if you're using it) I have no idea where that bug is, but investigating that bug could be useful for everyone under s similar configuration. As I said earlier, this has nothing to do with VLC. As both VLC and xdg-screensaver have a contract that seem to be a valid (a call to `reset`), which is supposed to `reset` the idle-countdown (as one would expect).

Comment: You seem you have the passion to pursue this issue, I was unable to reproduce it, if you know what you're using (xscreensaver, or the like) you may want to open the bug report with xdg-screensaver. https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Portland&component=xdg-utils

Comment: No "passion" here, I just pursued out of respect for the time you took to answer. My system is obsolete, and fine with my solution. I will not file a bug report before upgrading. For the record, here is the `xdg-utils` version used: `git describe --abbrev=40 --always --dirty=+` yields `c7ecf26e036c7a5f8a921d12c7efe1435f3e996b`. (this is the latest one)

Comment: So that gets me back to the original point, which is that the bug isn't reproducible =( No one knows the magic sauce to create it, or why your fix works: it's even pretty close to the pre_action which actually turns off dpms and turns it back on to reset the DPMS timer too: https://github.com/mtorromeo/xdg-utils/blob/master/scripts/xdg-screensaver.in#L81 If you're running on an obsolete system the bug could be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script which can close xscreensaver when VLC is open, and even closes redshift (eye protector app) when it exists.

You can try it from here:

[Close-Screensaver-Redshift-when-VLC-opened-Script](https://github.com/Pucur/Close-Screensaver-Redshift-when-VLC-opened-Script)